# Assembler Linking two Files and calling functions cross-file

Tags: assembly, makefile, linker

Is it possible inside one assembler (.S) file to call "functions" from other .S files?

Is this where `.global functionname` comes in handy?

If this is possible, what needs to be added to a generic Makefile, that right now just compiles the .C and .S file?

Comment: Yes, yes, and nothing.  It should just work™.

Comment: What assembler are you using? The GNU assembler?

Comment: Do you really use `.C` (capital C)?  I think I've heard of doing that for C++, but usually people use `.cc` or `.cpp`.  If so, beware of name-mangling (i.e. use `extern "C"` when declaring functions and global variables.)

Comment: .C was referring to it being a C-language file (name.c)

Comment: @fuz Iam using gcc